# Enhancing/smoothing Landsat 8 image using ArcGIS Online?

Tags: remote-sensing, arcgis-online, landsat-8

I understand that Landsat 8 is 30m resolution, but is there any technique that can be used to smooth/enhance the NDVI or Agriculture Landsat layers in an ArcGIS Online (AGOL) web map?

I have adjusted the image quality to 'best' but can I achieve better results than this for "Agriculture" or "Agriculture DRA" processing template;

[image]

Comment: It looks fairly awful, it's probably drawn from lossy compressed images too (that could be due to your image though). Perhaps there's better data available that's not ArcGis online. What area are you in? Is that Tasmania in Australia?

Comment: Michael, yes that is Tasmania in Australia. The image is the Landsat 8 layers through the AGOL service http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=8483d89e59904728b54f187b462a442c. I am aware of pan-sharpening through ArcGIS for Desktop, but am wanting something live, where I do not need to process images all the time and reupload to the web map.

Comment: The BOM has monthly NDVI downloads, not sure of cell size, all derived from NOAA http://noaasis.noaa.gov/NOAASIS/ml/avhrr.html. I think that's the best you've going to get from ArcGis Online, perhaps NOAA has a service.

Comment: Well I guess I can always turn off the Landsat Image in the AGOL at the desired resolution (ie when it begins to really look horrible). The Landsat AGOL service layers comes with our AGOL subscription account.

Comment: Hey Johnny, Simon here from Esri Aus.  Ill ask one of our imagery guys when he gets back from UC on Mon/Tue.  I think you have hit the limits from the landsat image service (and its available functions) on AGO. The only alternative would be what you want to avoid, downloading the landsat scene and doing some additional sharpening filters to see if you can further improve, tile package and upload. http://landsat.usgs.gov/LandsatLook_Viewer.php